# How to I configure the home.java variable for vscode in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk, visual-studio-code

In Eclipse, java development is seamless and works just fine. However, Visual Studio Code doesn't seem to recognize the java installation and demands that you manually input its whereabouts. I've had the same problem with the latter on Windows but was able to figure it out.

On Ubuntu Linux 16.04 I cannot seem to find the jdk. I DO have it installed. Is this a problem with openjdk specifically?